# What are machine learning algorithms which rank films?

Tags: algorithms, ranking

Broadly speaking, there are two approaches to producing lists of the *best* films: human vs machine curation.

Human curation involves someone, a critic, making decisions and/or creating a canon, based on some criteria for selection. This person specifies a subset of films which in their view belong in a pantheon of the best films ever made. Human curation is ad hoc, bespoke, subjective, thoughtful, usually involves a small set of information wrt criteria or features, and so on. Examples of this include the *AFI's 100 Best American Films; 1,000 Films to See Before You Die; A Cinema History* for the silent film era and books such as Gilbert Adair's *Flickers: An Illustrated Celebration of 100 Years of Cinema*, and many more. Criteria can include box office ticket sales, IMDB popularity ratings, critic's annual lists of *best of* reviews, industry awards, nominations, etc.

Machine curation, on the other hand, can involve large, even huge, amounts of data and features and an algorithm of some type which statistically evaluates films to produce a ranked list of the best films. Here, the most subjective part of the process involves the selection of features used and the films included, otherwise, the process is intended to be fully automated.

*Rotten Tomatoes* is an example of a hybrid approach to film curation as there is a panel of approved critics and a panel of people responsible for aggregating and rating the reviews of the approved critics, as explained on the *About Rotten Tomatoes* web page,

> Rotten Tomatoes has assembled a team of curators whose job it is to
> read thousands of movie and TV reviews weekly. The team collects movie
> and TV reviews from Tomatometer-approved critics and publications
> every day, generating Tomatometer scores. Our curators carefully read
> these reviews, noting if the reviews are Fresh or Rotten, and choose a
> representative pull-quote. Tomatometer-approved critics can also
> self-submit their reviews.
> https://www.rottentomatoes.com/about#whatisthetomatometer

I'm looking for something that is virtually 100% algorithmic, like a *Google PageRank* for films. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank

What algorithms are out there and what *best of* film lists have they produced?

Comment: How do you define 'best'?

Comment: @lpounng Thanks for your comment. How *I* define 'best' really isn't important. It's how the algorithms define it that matters.

Comment: It doesn't work this way. Algorithm works by us (human) giving it the objective as what do we consider good and bad. From your own example, vanilla Google's PageRank assumes a website ranks high if it is referred (linked to) from a lot of external sites, and this assumption is the given by the author.

Comment: Precise quote from Wiki: 'PageRank works by counting the number and quality of links to a page to determine a rough estimate of how important the website is. The underlying assumption is that more important websites are likely to receive more links from other websites.' - This assumption comes from the thinking of the authors of PageRank; PageRank did not dream this up.

Comment: @lpounng We're not yet living in a Terminator world where machines have achieved complete autonomy and consciousness. So, your point is obvious. Evidently mine is not, apologies for any lack of clarity.

Comment: So back to square 1 - given that for human or machine curation regardless we need to supply what a 'best' mean, what is the 'best' as per your objective?

Comment: I've already answered that.